# Log4j2 Is it possible to get rollingfile to be created immediately under specified conditions?

Tags: spring, log4j2

I have set the daily rollingfile settings.

The result works as intended, but there is a problem with the process.

For example, the log for January 1st was written and on January 2nd I wanted the log for January 1st to be rolled immediately.

However, in reality, this is not the case, and at least one log of January 2nd must occur before rolling works.

That is, if no new dated log occurs, the old log is not rolled out and is still maintained.

Is there any way to make it roll immediately according to the rollingfile condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `CronTriggeringPolicy` configured to trigger every day at midnight instead of the `TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy` for the daily rollover you already have, e.g.

```xml
<RollingFile ...>
    ...
    <Policies>
        <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0 * * ?" />
    </Policies>
    ...
</RollingFile>
```

(https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#Cron_Triggering_Policy)